# Optocoupler 5V to STM32F407 3.3V

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, digital-logic, stm32, opto-isolator

I have to connect 8 optocouplers as shown in the picture with STM32F407 MCU. These are giving 8 digital signals to the MCU.

[image: snippet of a schematic showing PC817 optocoupler]

The supply voltage at the outputs of optocouplers is 5V DC while the STM32F407 power supply is 3.3V DC. Which GPIO pins are safest to connect these digital signals on STM32F407 MCU?

Comment: Why did you do that?  You should supply the optos with the same voltage as the MCU.  Otherwise **read the data sheet** to see which pins are and are not 5v tolerant, however this is an inferior solution to simply using the right voltage to start with.

Comment: If i change the opto voltage then i will have to change the resistor value also. I want to avoid doing these changes.

Comment: No, you probably won't have to change the resistor.  It is really not that critical.

Comment: If this is a requirement to have 5V output from these optocouplers, then you may use 5V tolerant GPIOs, as suggested by Sagar below or use 5V-3.3V level shifters when none of such GPIOs is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if you have a STM32F407VE, look in the datasheet at [STM32F407VE](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f407ve.pdf). For other models, check http://www.st.com, type your model in the `search` field, and download the data sheet.

For the STM32F407VE, on page 46 and further, you can find the 5V tolerant pins, in the picture below marked with red boxes (same for other models in their data sheets).

[image: Fragment]

Comment: what is the definition of FT (5V tolerant)? is it safe enough to use as many FT GPIO's or any limit on that?

Comment: I cannot find any reference about that, so I assume it is no problem; of course there is a maximum current per GPIO (and a total for e.g. VCC/GND pins).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother about this.
Optocoupler is already providing isolation, 3.3V from MCU to optocoupler input is totally isolated with the output of the optocoupler.

Just need to be sure of the current source/sink from MCU to make the optocoupler work fine.